# Transform css scale in difference shape

Tags: css

I want to make an effect in CSS
[image]

I Already have A, B, and C Images, for example, I want to hover the A Image and the scale will be a bigger little bit, It's possible to make it like that?
as I know when we group the image, the image one by one will remain in the shape of a box, thanks.

Comment: Provide some code: `html` `css`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the CSS `transform:scale()`.
Try something like this:

```
.A:hover {
  transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

Also consider adding a `box-shadow` to give it a more raised effect.
Make sure A, B, and C are separate elements, if they are all in the same element than that makes this much more difficult.

If you would provide some code and more information about what you are trying to do then it might be easier to answer your question.